# How do I allow access to an AWS Elastic Load Balancer over the DNS name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have an ELB. It has the address `myelbname.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` as one would expect.

I also have an EC2 instance behind that ELB. The load balancer is saying that the instance is healthy (the status is "In Service").

I can access the EC2 instance over IP on my network (using VPN to the VPC) but if I go to the A record of the load balancer in a browser then it can't be found.

Also, if I run `nslookup` it does show an IP address for the load balancer.

I've also tried adding a CNAME record and pointing it to the ELB's DNS name but that didn't work.

Comment: Make sure your ELB is placed in AZs with an internet gateway, so they can access the public internet.

Comment: The VPC has an internet gateway (as far as I can see you can't assign an intenet gateway to an AZ, just the VPC)

Comment: Sorry, should've said subnet.

Comment: Can you make that an answer please.

Comment: Certainly, I have done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ELBs must be in a subnet with an internet gateway. Placing an ELB in a private subnet makes it only available within the VPC's network.

Comment: Or, more precisely, in a subnet with a default route pointing to the Internet gateway (not a NAT instance).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is VPN or DirectConnect connection. If you create VPN or DirectConnect connection to you vpc from your corporate network, then you will be able to access all the resources from the corporate network.